# Percent encoding javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, percent-encoding

Is there a javascript function that takes a string and converts it into another string that is percent-encoded? That way something like "This Guy" turns into "This%20Guy".

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try **encodeURIComponent()** or **escape()**

Comment: Note: This does not work for encoding the char '%' itself. Took me along time to find out I had to use "encodeURI"

Answer (score 49):

`encodeURI`, `encodeURIComponent` or `escape` will work the same way for *your* string, but they differ in details.

`encodeURI` is just for escaping URLs
`encodeURIComponent` also escapes `=` and `&`
`escape` works differently with non-ASCII unicode symbols

```
encodeURI("Ω") === encodeURIComponent("Ω") === "%CE%A9"
escape("Ω") === "%u03A9"
```

if you need to send a string as part of request, use encodeURIComponent

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it explains also a bit of differences,.. instead of currently accepted answer saying: Try encodeURIComponent() or escape()

Answer (score 4):

Try this `encodeURIComponent()`

```
var stringToDecode = "J&K";

var encodedString = encodeURIComponent(stringToDecode );
```

Use `decodeURIComponent()` to decode it again when needed

More Info here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: When I use encodeURIComponent for a string with an ampersand, it encodes the ampersand as J&amp;K.  This makes it to the server, but decodeURIComponent doesn't recover the string and it remains as J&amp;K

Comment: @Laura what language is at the server side?

Comment: Node.js, so javascript.  I figured out what the problem was.  For some reason the browser changed the & in the original string to "&amp;" when I accessed it in the client JQuery. So when I encoded it, it encoded "&amp;" to "%XXamp%XX", then the server decoded that to "&amp;".  Once I saw that, I changed my process to account for that unexpected conversion and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is

```
escape('This Guy');
```