# Values change after JSON AJAX POST (percentage symbol)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I got a problem. I am building some kind of a slide editor with AJAX.
I have a PHP script which has many functions which can be selected with different GET parameters.
Everything works fine. But when I try to post the slides to save them, a value called transformorigin changes from 50% 50% 0 to 50500.

GET slide.php?action=get&id=1

```
[{"slideid":1,"position":1,"background":{"id":"3","name":"http:\/\/test.com\/uploads\/1\/img\/20140729_174513.jpg"},"delay":4000,"timeshift":0,"active":true,"transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":1000,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50% 50% 0","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":-80,"offsety":0,"duration":400,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50% 50% 0","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}},{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":1000,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50% 50% 0","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":-80,"offsety":0,"duration":400,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50% 50% 0","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}}]},{"slideid":2,"position":2,"background":{"id":"4","name":"http:\/\/test.com\/uploads\/1\/img\/20140729_174608.jpg"},"delay":4000,"timeshift":0,"active":true,"transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[]}]
```

POST slide.php?action=post&id=1

```
[{"slideid":1,"position":1,"background":{"id":"3","name":"http:\/\/test.com\/uploads\/1\/img\/20140729_174513.jpg"},"delay":4000,"timeshift":0,"active":true,"transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":1000,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50500","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":400,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50500","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}},{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":1000,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50500","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":400,"delay":0,"fade":true,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"50500","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}}]},{"slideid":2,"position":2,"background":{"id":"4","name":"http:\/\/test.com\/uploads\/1\/img\/20140729_174608.jpg"},"delay":4000,"timeshift":0,"active":true,"transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[]}]
```

I don't understand why transformorigin changes after the POST.
When I click on the firebug post tab of the post request, it is still 50% 50% 0.
But server side I get 50500 when I do a

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

at the begining.

Here is my Javascript/jQuery:

```
function saveSlides(success,error) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/slide.php?action=post&id=' + lid,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(slides),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
      if ("undefined" == typeof(data.error)) {
        slides = data;
        if (isFunction(success))
          success(data);
      } else {
        if (isFunction(error))
          error(data);
      }
    },error: function() {
      if (isFunction(error))
        error({"error":{"id":100,"message":"Could not retrieve data."}});
    }
  });
}
```

And even when I specify contentType it doesn't change the content type.

Thank you in advance

UPDATE 1:

After encoding everything with JavaScript, this is what I send to the php script:

```
[{"slideid":"1","position":"1","background":{"id":"3","name":"http%3A//test.com/uploads/1/img/20140729_174513.jpg"},"delay":"4000","timeshift":"0","active":"true","transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":"80","offsety":"0","duration":"1000","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":"-80","offsety":"0","duration":"400","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}},{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":"80","offsety":"0","duration":"1000","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":"-80","offsety":"0","duration":"400","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}}]},{"slideid":"2","position":"2","background":{"id":"4","name":"http%3A//test.com/uploads/1/img/20140729_174608.jpg"},"delay":"4000","timeshift":"0","active":"true","transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[]}]
```

This is what I get back from the php script:

```
[{"slideid":1,"position":1,"background":{"id":"3","name":"http:\/\/test.com\/uploads\/1\/img\/20140729_174513.jpg"},"delay":4000,"timeshift":0,"active":false,"transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":1000,"delay":0,"fade":false,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"5025205025200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":400,"delay":0,"fade":false,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"5025205025200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}},{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":1000,"delay":0,"fade":false,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"5025205025200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":80,"offsety":0,"duration":400,"delay":0,"fade":false,"rotate":0,"rotatex":0,"rotatey":0,"skewx":0,"skewy":0,"scalex":1,"scaley":1,"transformorigin":"5025205025200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}}]},{"slideid":2,"position":2,"background":{"id":"4","name":"http:\/\/test.com\/uploads\/1\/img\/20140729_174608.jpg"},"delay":4000,"timeshift":0,"active":false,"transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[]}]
```

So now it changes from 50%25%2050%25%200 to 5025205025200.

After i added a urldecode to my php script it returned 50500 again.

UPDATE 2:

Now I am trying to test the php file.

When I do this:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
die;
```

I get back the same I send:

```
[{"slideid":"1","position":"1","background":{"id":"3","name":"http%3A//test.com/uploads/1/img/20140729_174513.jpg"},"delay":"4000","timeshift":"0","active":"true","transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":"80","offsety":"0","duration":"1000","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":"-80","offsety":"0","duration":"400","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}},{"background":[],"tag":"h1","content":"Test","style":{"top":"0px","left":"0px"},"transitionin":{"offsetx":"80","offsety":"0","duration":"1000","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}},"transitionout":{"offsetx":"-80","offsety":"0","duration":"400","delay":"0","fade":"true","rotate":"0","rotatex":"0","rotatey":"0","skewx":"0","skewy":"0","scalex":"1","scaley":"1","transformorigin":"50%25%2050%25%200","easing":{"id":14,"name":"easeInOutQuint"}}}]},{"slideid":"2","position":"2","background":{"id":"4","name":"http%3A//test.com/uploads/1/img/20140729_174608.jpg"},"delay":"4000","timeshift":"0","active":"true","transition2d":[2,7,9],"transition3d":[],"layers":[]}]
```

And when I do this:

```
$slides = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
print_r($slides);
die;
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [slideid] => 1
        [position] => 1
        [background] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => http%3A//test.com/uploads/1/img/20140729_174513.jpg
            )

        [delay] => 4000
        [timeshift] => 0
        [active] => true
        [transition2d] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 7
                [2] => 9
            )

        [transition3d] => Array
            (
            )

        [layers] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [background] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [tag] => h1
                        [content] => Test
                        [style] => Array
                            (
                                [top] => 0px
                                [left] => 0px
                            )

                        [transitionin] => Array
                            (
                                [offsetx] => 80
                                [offsety] => 0
                                [duration] => 1000
                                [delay] => 0
                                [fade] => true
                                [rotate] => 0
                                [rotatex] => 0
                                [rotatey] => 0
                                [skewx] => 0
                                [skewy] => 0
                                [scalex] => 1
                                [scaley] => 1
                                [transformorigin] => 50%25%2050%25%200
                                [easing] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 14
                                        [name] => easeInOutQuint
                                    )

                            )

                        [transitionout] => Array
                            (
                                [offsetx] => -80
                                [offsety] => 0
                                [duration] => 400
                                [delay] => 0
                                [fade] => true
                                [rotate] => 0
                                [rotatex] => 0
                                [rotatey] => 0
                                [skewx] => 0
                                [skewy] => 0
                                [scalex] => 1
                                [scaley] => 1
                                [transformorigin] => 50%25%2050%25%200
                                [easing] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 14
                                        [name] => easeInOutQuint
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [background] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [tag] => h1
                        [content] => Test
                        [style] => Array
                            (
                                [top] => 0px
                                [left] => 0px
                            )

                        [transitionin] => Array
                            (
                                [offsetx] => 80
                                [offsety] => 0
                                [duration] => 1000
                                [delay] => 0
                                [fade] => true
                                [rotate] => 0
                                [rotatex] => 0
                                [rotatey] => 0
                                [skewx] => 0
                                [skewy] => 0
                                [scalex] => 1
                                [scaley] => 1
                                [transformorigin] => 50%25%2050%25%200
                                [easing] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 14
                                        [name] => easeInOutQuint
                                    )

                            )

                        [transitionout] => Array
                            (
                                [offsetx] => -80
                                [offsety] => 0
                                [duration] => 400
                                [delay] => 0
                                [fade] => true
                                [rotate] => 0
                                [rotatex] => 0
                                [rotatey] => 0
                                [skewx] => 0
                                [skewy] => 0
                                [scalex] => 1
                                [scaley] => 1
                                [transformorigin] => 50%25%2050%25%200
                                [easing] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 14
                                        [name] => easeInOutQuint
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [slideid] => 2
        [position] => 2
        [background] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => http%3A//test.com/uploads/1/img/20140729_174608.jpg
            )

        [delay] => 4000
        [timeshift] => 0
        [active] => true
        [transition2d] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 7
                [2] => 9
            )

        [transition3d] => Array
            (
            )

        [layers] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

So now I have to decode it somehow.

UPDATE 3:

I had to use **encodeURIComponent()** inside javascript and **urldecode()** inside php.

Thank you very much now it works.

Comment: After your edit, it seems like something may be going wrong in your PHP script. What is the code for the script? You say the part with % is the response, correct?

Comment: I edited my text, maybe you understand it better. Now I will upload add parts of the php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is being interpreted as [character encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encode#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) as it it prefaced by a % sign. See also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911820/percent-encoding-javascript). Can you escape it before it is processed?

You can encode your text after you stringify the object, and then decode it when it reaches you. Check the higher voted answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506000/javascript-json-stringify-doesnt-escape).

Comment: Do you mean to escape it server side with PHP ?
Or with Javascript before the post ?

Comment: My suggestion is to do it with JavaScript pre-post, but I am considering if I may be wrong. Let me know, if it doesn't work it may be best for me to remove my answer so you can get new ones in more easily. Could you try to put the escape around the JSON stringify result? Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506000/javascript-json-stringify-doesnt-escape

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work for me. I have to escape every value and call JSON stringify after that.

Comment: You  got it to work by escaping the values, then using JSON stringify, instead of the other way around? That's a bit odd.

Comment: Not yet. I got some problems.

Comment: I am not able to escape it. I always get ["%5Bobject%20Object%5D", "%5Bobject%20Object%5D", "%5Bobject%20Object%5D"].

Comment: The order is going wrong. Consider the difference in output between escape({la:"la"}); and escape(JSON.stringify({la:"la"}));

Comment: When I add urldecode to my php script. The result is the same as when I wouldn't escape it.